# Sending email via SES in localstack, with an event destination with a sns topic, not working

Tags: aws-cli, localstack

I am trying to receive a message in a queue when triggering an email with SES in localstack. The SES service is using an event destination that connects to a SNS topic. The SNS topic is connected to a queue, where I want to receive the bounce, click information.

Here are the steps:

```
// 1 whitelist email sender
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ses verify-email-identity --email-address sender@test.com --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat

// 2 create sqs queue
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs create-queue --queue-name ses_events_queue --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat

// 3 create sns topic
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sns create-topic --name ses_events_topic --region eu-central-1 --profile test-profile --output table

// 4 subscribe sqs queue to sns topic
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sns subscribe --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:000000000000:ses_events_topic --protocol sqs --notification-endpoint arn:aws:sqs:eu-central-1:000000000000:ses_events_queue --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat
```

up until here, if I publish a message with:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sns publish --topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:000000000000:ses_events_topic --message "{\"subject\":\"Subject\",\"body8\":\"Body 8\",\"from\":\"test@test.com\",\"to\":\"to@ta.com\"}" --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat
```

it works, I can see message in queue.

Now the SES setup:

```
// 5 create config set
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ses create-configuration-set --configuration-set "{\"Name\":\"ses_config_set\"}" --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat

// 6 create event destination
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ses create-configuration-set-event-destination --configuration-set-name ses_config_set --event-destination '{"Name":"some_name2","Enabled":true,"MatchingEventTypes":["send","bounce","delivery","open"],"SNSDestination":{"TopicARN":"arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:000000000000:ses_events_topic"}}' --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat
```

And now the actual sending of the email:

```
// 7 send email via ses using config set
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ses send-email --destination '{"ToAddresses":["receiver@mail.com"]}' --message '{"Subject":{"Data":"some sub","Charset":"string"},"Body":{"Text":{"Data":"some tesxt body","Charset":"string"}}}' --configuration-set-name ses_config_set --from 'sender@test.com' --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat
```

Email is sent, but if I check messages in queue, there's none:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs receive-message --queue-url http://localhost:4566/000000000000/ses_events_queue --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1  --output table | cat
```

Not sure where the error is. I'm also not sure what is the best way to debug. I tried to use `--debug` in the email sending, but I can't find anything useful.

My suspicion is that the `create event destination` step can be wrong, since there are may options inside, but not sure.

I've also tried to add permissions to the queue:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 sqs set-queue-attributes --queue-url http://localhost:4566/000000000000/ses_events_queue --attributes file://set_queue_attributes.json --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat
```

in `set_queue_attributes.json`:

```
{"Policy" : "{\"Id\": \"Policy1564523767951\",\"Version\": \"2012-10-17\",\"Statement\": [{\"Sid\": \"Stmt1564523766749\",\"Action\": \"sqs:*\",\"Effect\": \"Allow\",\"Resource\": \"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:12345678:example-queue\",\"Condition\": {\"ArnEquals\": {\"aws:SourceArn\": \"arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:73628827939:MySNS\"}},\"Principal\": \"*\"}]}"}
```

But it does not work either. Not sure if this might be the issue, because publishing directly to `sns`, I can see the `queue` receiving the message. I don't know how to debug, that `ses` sends the message, and that `ses` publishes a message in the `sns` topic

Answer (score 0):

[In the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/configure-sns-notifications.html), they state

> Whether you create a new SNS topic or select an existing one, you need to give access to SES to publish notifications to the topic.

In your case, try to add this permission, after step 3 //create sns topic

```
awslocal sns add-permission \
--topic-arn arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:000000000000:ses_events_topic \
--label Publish-Permission \
--aws-account-id 000000000000 \
--action-name Publish
```

I use the thin wrapper [awslocal](https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/integrations/aws-cli/#localstack-aws-cli-awslocal)

Also, use option "--max-number-of-messages 10" in "sqs receive-message".
Default is "1"

Comment: they didn't have this implementation at the time. I opened an issue and they added it: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/7184

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I started using LocalStack a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

the reason it was not working was because the feature was not implemented. I opened an issue and they worked fast on it:
https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/7184

I post this answer in case anyone finds something similar