# How to set event-destination for a configuration set in AWS CLI using SES and localstack

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-sns, amazon-ses, localstack

I am trying to listen to events when sending emails via `SES` in `localstack`. I have created corresponding `queues` and `SNS` topics.

I define a configuration set for when sending email:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ses create-configuration-set --configuration-set "{\"Name\":\"ses_config_set\"}" --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat
```

I define the `event destination`:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ses create-configuration-set-event-destination --configuration-set-name ses_config_set --event-destination '{"Name":"some_name2","Enabled":true,"MatchingEventTypes":["send","bounce","delibery","open","click"],"SNSDestination":{"TopicARN":"arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:000000000000:ses_events_topic"}}' --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat
```

I've also tried to define the `event destination` via file:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ses create-configuration-set-event-destination --configuration-set-name ses_config_set --event-destination file://set_event_destination_attrs.json --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat

// set_event_destination_attrs.json

{
  "Name": "string some",
  "Enabled": true,
  "MatchingEventTypes": ["send","reject","bounce","complaint","delivery","open","click","renderingFailure"],
  "SNSDestination": {
    "TopicARN": "arn:aws:sns:eu-central-1:000000000000:ses_events_topic"
  }
}
```

Both `ses create-configuration-set-event-destination` commands seem to work, no error is given in the console.

But when sending an email using this `config set`:

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 ses send-email --destination '{"ToAddresses":["receiver@mail.com"]}' --message '{"Subject":{"Data":"foo subject","Charset":"string"},"Body":{"Text":{"Data":"foo body","Charset":"string"}}}' --configuration-set-name ses_config_set --from 'sender@test.com' --profile test-profile --region eu-central-1 --output table | cat
```

I can't see any event in my queue. Theoretically, `SES` should send an `event` to the `SNS` topic (like bounce, click etc.), and the queue is subscribed to the `SNS`. Publishing a message from the `SNS` topic to the queue works fine.

1. I have the suspicion that the `create-configuration-set-event-destination` might be wrong. Maybe the `--event-destination` json, the format, etc.
2. How can I debug that the `event destination` is properly set?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74436394/sending-email-via-ses-in-localstack-with-an-event-destination-with-a-sns-topic/75440135#75440135) can help you find the solution. It's a similar question

Comment: they didn't have this implementation at the time, I opened an issue and they added it: https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/7184